# Hibernate Dirty checking exception

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate when modify object didn't got dirty check exception

```
public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
             Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
             cfg=cfg.configure();
             SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
             Session ss=sf.openSession();
             Customer cc=new Customer("hai","hai@gmail.com");
             Customer person = (Customer)ss.get(Customer.class, new Integer(1));
             System.out.println(person.getEmail());
             //when modify then i didn't got dirtycheckexception
             person.setEmail("kkk");
             Transaction tx=ss.beginTransaction();
             tx.commit();
             ss.flush();
             Session ss1=sf.openSession();
```

when modify email I didn't got hibernateexception

Comment: can share the detailed log for further clarification on your issue?

Comment: Hibernate: select customer0_.sid as sid0_0_, customer0_.name as name0_0_, customer0_.email as email0_0_ from kop customer0_ where customer0_.sid=?
poi
poi

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a `ss.update(person)` to tell Hibernate to perform the update on database when you commit the transaction.
At commit time a dirty-check is performed to check which properties needs to be updated; no dirty-check is performed when you change a bean property (and this is the reason why you are not getting a "dirty checking" exception)

Comment: ss.update(person);
     person.setEmail("poi"); i put this code code i didn't got exception

Comment: Maybe the opposite: `person.setEmail("poi"); ss.update(person);` but only if email is the PK (or you have a unique index on table): beside all, from my memories, I don't remember any "dirty checking" exception

Answer (score 0):

From my understating, all the DB talks should happen only inside the transactions. But In your code, you are opening the transaction only at end where transaction not even required/used. **I’m expecting error while you run your code**. Kindly correct me if I’m wrong here.

You are modifying the state of the object but it’s not posted for DB update. In this case No dirty check will be performed.

Comment: ss.update(person);
     person.setEmail("poi");i put this code inside transction but i didn't got exception

Comment: As everyone mentioned, Dirty check will happen only when you post your changes to database. something like session.update();